# Prolog not writing to file

Tags: file-io, prolog

```
command(A) :-
   open('tree.txt',write,Stream),
   (  s(X,A,[]),
      write(Stream,X),
      fail
   ;  true
   ),
   close(Stream).
```

In the above code I am attempting to write the consequent syntax tree of a sentence to a file called tree.txt. s(x,A,[]) represents the sentence I am calling, where X is the syntax tree. I am calling this predicate while running the grammar in SWI Prolog and getting a "true" value returned, however the syntax tree is not being written to the text file (in the same directory as my grammar file).

The whole grammar file is as follows (if necessary):

```
command(A) :- open('tree.txt',write,Stream),
      (s(X,A,[]) , write(Stream,X), fail;true),
      close(Stream).
% writer(X) :- open('tree.txt', write,Stream),
%        write(Stream,X),
%        close(Stream).
s(s(X)) --> cmd(X).
s(s(X)) --> assertion(X).
s(s(X)) --> qstn(X).
qstn(qstn(qw,subject,X)) --> qw, subject, np(X).
qstn(qstn(qw,is,X)) --> qw, [is], np(X).
assertion(assertion(subject,is,X)) --> subject, [is], np(X).
cmd(cmd(X,Y)) --> v(X), np(Y).
np(np(det,X)) --> det, n(X).
np(np(X)) --> n(X).
np(np(adj,X)) --> adj, n(X).
n(n(A)) --> [A], {lex(A,n)}.
v(v(A)) --> [A], {lex(A,v)}.
qw --> [A], {lex(A,qw)}.
det --> [A], {lex(A,det)}.
adj --> [A], {lex(A,adj)}.
subject --> [A], {lex(A,subject)}.

lex(this,subject).
lex(that,subject).
lex(build, v).
lex(move, v).
lex(walk, v).
lex(is,v).
lex(block, n).
lex(structure,n).
lex(where, qw).
lex(is, qw).
lex(what, qw).
lex(the, det).
lex(a, det).
lex(at, conj).
lex(on, conj).
```

where the "writer/1" function was an earlier attempt at writing to file.
I can provide more information if necessary, and I've tried what was suggested in another similar question (didn't work).
Can anybody help me?

Comment: It works for me. You do need to give it something that will allow `s(X,A,[])` to succeed. Try, for example, `command([build, the, block]).`

Comment: 10 ?- command([build,the,block]).
true.

writing the simplest possible sentence but it still isn't writing to file
are you using a different runtime environment than the IDE's inbuilt one?

Comment: I am running SWI Prolog on Linux. If you're running the IDE, that I assume you're on Windows? Are you saying that simple sentences work for you but not more complex ones? Can you clarify with an example failure? In the case I tried, it wrote to the file no problem.

Comment: What I meant was that no matter what kind of sentence I give the IDE, whether it evaluates as true or false, nothing gets written to the file.